# Index Of String read from file via AJAX makes no sense whatsoever

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, io

I have read a file using AJAX. The returned value is stored into a string. With that being said, i need to do some text parsing on it. I decided to create a little code block that outputs the value of the string linked with its index value.. the result makes absolutely no sense. I am also sure the code to show this is right as well.

Javascript:

```
    function removeFromFile(command, file){
        if (command.length <= 4){
            var api = command[3];
            $.ajax({
                url: 'process.php?fName=' + file,
                type: 'POST',
                datatype: "html",
                cache: false,
                async: false,
                data: {displayFile : true},
                success: function (r) {
                    output(r);
                    for (var i =0; i < r.length; i++){
                        output(r[i] + "    " + r.indexOf(r[i]));
                    }
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert('Something went wrong in the update! Ref: ');
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

The txt file looks like this:

```
    123-12333 : Duan Uys 
    345-34555 : Dennis Taylor
```

The output looks like this: Where it is coupled like so: value/ index_value

The value/index_value does not make sense at all?

```
    123-12333 : Duan Uys 

    345-34555 : Dennis Taylor 

    1    0
    2    1
    3    2
    -    3
    1    0
    2    1
    3    2
    3    2
    3    2
         9
    :    10
         9
    D    12
    u    13
    a    14
    n    15
         9
    U    17
    y    18
    s    19
         9

        21

        21
    3    2
    4    24
    5    25
    -    3
    3    2
    4    24
    5    25
    5    25
    5    25
         9
    :    10
         9
    D    12
    e    36
    n    15
    n    15
    i    39
    s    19
         9
    T    42
    a    14
    y    18
    l    45
    o    46
    r    47
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`indexOf` returns the first index matching the thing you're searching for. So every time you encounter a "1" in the string, it'll return 0 because that's the first index which contains "1" in the string.

There's no need to use `indexOf` anyway. Just use `i`. It represents the current index of the character you're logging to the console.

```
output(r[i] + "    " + i);
```